# Does version 11 have this bug in FourierSeries?

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis

**Bug introduced in 7.0.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.1**

---

I am using version 10.0 with Apple OS X. Consider the following.

```
f[t_]:=1/(1+25.0*(t-0.3)^2);
Plot[f[t],{t,-1,1}]
```

[image]

Below FourierSeries retruns the wrong series.

```
WrongSeries[t_]=Chop@Expand@ExpToTrig@FourierSeries[
f[t],t,4,FourierParameters->{1,\[Pi]}];
Plot[WrongSeries[t],{t,-1,1},
PlotLabel->Style["The Wrong Truncated Fourier Series",14,Bold]]
```

[image]

Does Version 11 also have this problem?

-----EDIT-----

I can derive the right series using a combination of FourierCosSeries and FourierSinSeries.

```
RightSeries[t_]=Expand[(
FourierCosSeries[f[t]+f[-t],t,4,FourierParameters->{1,\[Pi]}]+
FourierSinSeries[f[t]-f[-t],t,7,FourierParameters->{1,\[Pi]}])/2
];
Plot[{f[t],RightSeries[t]},{t,-1,1},
PlotLegends->{"g[t]","Truncated Fourier Series"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi; I run 11.0 on linux and I get that too.

Comment: Same with 11.0 on Windows.  [Image](http://imgur.com/a/2g84o)

Comment: Sadly, the same bug even with version 7.0.1 on Win7x64.

Comment: I can confirm that the bug is present in MMA 11.1.0.

Comment: The same issue in version 12.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in `FourierSeries`, and appears to be caused by the default setting `GenerateConditions -> False` which is used while computing the underlying integrals.

A workaround for the problem is to use `GenerateConditions -> True`, as shown below.

```
f[t_] := 1/(1 + 25.0 * (t - 0.3)^2);
FSeries[t_] = Chop @ Expand @ ExpToTrig @ FourierSeries[f[t], t, 4,
    FourierParameters -> {1, Pi}, GenerateConditions -> True];
```

[image: plot]

Thank your for reporting this issue, and sorry for the inconvenience.